# PHP - Submit data and save it to database from Vue 3 front-end form using Slim 4

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, slim

I'm writing a simple app that will collect instagram images links from peoples to show them as featured on the homepage. I have successfully setup a vuejs front-end and I'm working to implement instagram links submission form. Since I want to avoid using headless wordpress that is shipped with the app, I'm thinking to use Slim 4 to set some endpoints to save and fetch data. The problem is that I don't know how to serve the `index.html` file that is running my Vue SPA.

Another option I have is to develop the app using node but the production server doesn't support it so to avoid deploy the app on heroku that will not have an included database and that will not persist files when dyno are not running, the only way to go is with PHP.

At the moment my form component looks like the code below, I've created an instance of axios but I don't have already added Slim 4 to the project to manage requests.

```js
<template>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row m-0">
   <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
    <label>Instagram poto link</label> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="https://instagram.com/p/CM4VGOkDaZ/" v-model="igLink">
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="submitPhotoLink()">SUBMIT</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  data() {
   return { igLink: '' }
  }
  created() {},
  mounted() {},
  computed: {},
  methods: {
   submitPhotoLink() {
     axios({  
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://my-site.com/linkendpoint'
      data: { iglink: this.igLink }
     }).then( (res) => { console.log(res) });
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

Anyone can point me into the right direction? On the backend, to connect and save data into db I will use Redbean so at the moment I need help to serve the `index.html` file when the `/` route in slim front controller is reached. In the vue app the views are managed using `vue-router` as I know there is no conflict with slim routing, is this right?

Comment: As to the database, are you planning on using any of the other WordPress features? Having built headless WordPress implementations before, I can tell you that the more you fight WordPress (or don’t use it) the more you wish you had just used a simple database. But, if there are other reasons for WP, use it.

Comment: @ChrisHaas The initial thing was to create a custom role to assign to each new users after registration using custom form and REST api. Since the user registration is overkill for my scope, I've decidet to go just with a simple form where everyone can put an isntagram link to a public image and then send it to store into the database. This mean tha at the moment wordpress has no utility in the project. I want to go with slim 4 but I don't know how to send to the main route `/` the index.html file that run the vue SPA

Comment: Sounds like you’ve got a good plan to start with them. My recommendation is to edit this post with that information and remove the WP parts which will hopefully get you a solid answer then

Comment: ok, thank you for the suggestion, I'm editing my question. I hope to find someone who can help me